# Getting React unique ID in didMount

Tags: input, reactjs, components, semantic-ui

I have a custom react Input component. I want all my inputs to have a small hint beside them (an asterix) that on hover shows a hint. The problem is I cannot make the initialization of the popup point to this exact asterix so it shows the message for this particular component. Right now it just replaces the message with the message of the last mounted component.

My question is - how would I reference the exact  element. Can I get the React ID from didMount? Can I point to it using render, something like $(this.render() + ' i') -> (ideal case).

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

export default class Input extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    var html = this.props.popup;
    console.log(this);
    $('.inverted.asterisk.icon').popup({
      html: html,
      variation: 'inverted'
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui icon fluid input">
       <input
              type={this.props.type}
              value={this.props.value}
              onChange={this.props.onChange}
              name={this.props.name}
       />
       <i className="inverted disabled asterisk link icon" />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Input.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  popup: PropTypes.string,
  value: PropTypes.node,
  onChange: PropTypes.func
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) attribute to any element inside your render function to get a reference to it.

Assign the ref

```
<i ref="icon" className="inverted disabled asterisk link icon" />
```

Use it in componentDidMount

```
  componentDidMount() {
    var html = this.props.popup;
    console.log(this);
    $(this.refs.icon).popup({
      html: html,
      variation: 'inverted'
    });
  }
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/43605/)

Comment: That is amazing! Thank you!